# GWT, RootPanel.get() is null

Tags: gwt

I'm following a beginner's tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gwt/gwt_style_with_css.htm. 
The code for the HelloWorld.html file is:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="HelloWorld.css"/>
   <script language="javascript" src="helloworld/helloworld.nocache.js">
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mytext"><h1>Hello, World!</h1></div>
<div id="gwtGreenButton"></div>
<div id="gwtRedButton"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

In the HelloWorld.java (extending EntryPoint), I have:

```
RootPanel.get("gwtGreenButton").add(Btn1);
RootPanel.get("gwtRedButton").add(Btn2);
```

The 2 lines: RootPanel.get() always result in null. I don't know what happen, what to check? (too bad the site doesn't have a comment/discussion section)

Thanks.

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers? In devmode or prod-mode? (or both?) Didn't you double-check the IDs are exactly the same? Would be interesting to know if moving the `<script>` just before `</body>` changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Docs says

[**RootPanel.get(java.lang.String id)**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29)

> Gets the root panel associated with a given browser element.

[**DOM.getElementById(java.lang.String)**](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#getElementById%28java.lang.String%29)

> Gets the element associated with the given unique id within the entire document.

Try with

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.getElementById("gwtGreenButton");

com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.getElementById("gwtRedButton");
```